# Read message iOS tweak with theos

Tags: ios, jailbreak, theos, entitlements

I'm trying to make an app which intercept and delete received messages with specific content. (The user might not read them).

I found this code on iPhoneDevWiki :

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
@implementation RootViewController
- (void)loadView {
    self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]] autorelease];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(readAwesomeMessage:) name:@"CKConversationMessageReadNotification" object:nil];

}
-(void)readAwesomeMessage:(NSNotification *)notif {

for (NSString *key in [notif.userInfo allKeys]) {
    id value = [notif.userInfo objectForKey:key];
    NSLog(@"Class: %@ - Value : %@",[value class],value);
}

}
@end
```

I have two entitlements : com.apple.CommCenter.Messages-send and com.apple.coretelephony.Identity.get

And in the console I can see:

```
Mar  2 17:07:05 iPhone backboardd[38] <Error>: HID: The 'Passive' connection 'ReadMessage' access to protected services is denied.
```

I don't know if I must change the entitlements, or ?
Any help will be great...